# How to properly install matplotlib on mac 10.7.5? And why is the command "conda" not found after Anaconda is successfully installed?

Tags: python, matplotlib, osx-lion, ipython, conda

I tried for a long time to work with python on this Mac. I tried to remove python completely from my mac. Then I realized it was hard to get rid of this default python. Fortunately, I read in the internet that it's a bad idea to remove that one python that come with Mac before I figured out how to remove it. Then I also installed python, numpy, scipy, matplotlib using *.dmg packages. After all the effort, I still get this error message every time I import pylab. Please help me? Anyone?

```
$python

Python 2.7.4 (v2.7.4:026ee0057e2d, Apr  6 2013, 11:43:10) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pylab


Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.1.0-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg/pylab.py", line 1, in <module>
  from matplotlib.pylab import *
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.1.0-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg/matplotlib/pylab.py", line 221, in <module>
 `from matplotlib import mpl  # pulls in most modules
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.1.0-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg/matplotlib/mpl.py", line 2, in <module>
 `from matplotlib import axis
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.1.0-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg/matplotlib/axis.py", line 14, in <module>
 `import matplotlib.text as mtext
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.1.0-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg/matplotlib/text.py", line 31, in <module>
 `from matplotlib.backend_bases import RendererBase
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.1.0-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 48, in <module>
 `import matplotlib.textpath as textpath
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.1.0-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg/matplotlib/textpath.py", line 9, in <module>
 `from matplotlib.mathtext import MathTextParser
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.1.0-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg/matplotlib/mathtext.py", line 52, in <module>
 `import matplotlib._png as _png
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.1.0-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg/matplotlib/_png.so, 2): Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libpng14.14.dylib
Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.1.0-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg/matplotlib/_png.so
Reason: image not found
```

Besides, I followed the instruction on http://ipython.org/install.html to install Anaconda. After Anaconda is installed I went to the next step

```
$ conda update conda
```

and got this

```
"-bash: conda: command not found"
```

I searched in the net, but it seems no one else has this problem. Can anyone give me a hint here? Many thanks!

---

In my directory /usr/bin I have

```
python python-config python2.5 python2.5-config python2.6 python2.6-config python2.7 python2.7-config
```

With command
    which python

I got `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python`

with
    which ipython

I got `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/ipython`

For numpy I downloaded the package numpy-1.7.0-py2.7-python.org-macosx10.6.dmg, scipy-0.12.0-py2.7-python.org-macosx10.6.dmg for scipy, and matplotlib-1.2.0-py2.7-python.org-macosx10.6.dmg for matplotbib.I downloaded *10.6.dmg because that's what I found...I can not find something like *10.7.dmg

I don't have .bashrc or .bashrc_profile. But I think .profile will do, and it reads like this

```
# MacPorts Installer addition on 2012-03-07_at_18:55:26: adding an appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts.
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.
export TERM="xterm-color"
alias ls="ls -G"
export PS1="[\[\e[33m\]\u@\H \[\e[32m\]\w\[\e[0m\]]\n[\[\e[31m\]\!\[\e[0m\]] > "
# Setting PATH for Python 2.7
# The orginal version is saved in .profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

When I type in

$port

it says `-bash: port: command not found`
Should that worry me?
Shall I also out comment the line

> `export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH`

as well?

Comment: How did you install things? Did you install binaries? From where? 10.7 has Python by default at `/usr/bin/python`, though that's version 2.7.1 I think.

Comment: These days, I would recommend trying [Homebrew](http://mxcl.github.io/homebrew/). But, I would then also recommend removing all the stuff you installed just now (ask if you like more info on that), before things start to clash. Then, after installing python, you have to adjust your `PATH` a bit and use `pip` to install all the other packages (ipython, mpl, numpy etc etc).

Comment: You're on 10.7.5 and you installed 10.6 dmg files? Why? It may work, but it would potentially lead to incompatibilities.

Comment: I suggest the following: 1/ Edit your question with any extra comments you have (don't fill up comment space here), 2/ show your `${HOME}/.bashrc` and `${HOME}/.bash_profile` (if you have them): we'll need to know which line sets your `PATH` to point to this installed Python (and whether your `PYTHONPATH` is also messed up). From there, I may be able to give you an answer to solve this.

Comment: I've updated my answer regarding the homebrew path. You may run into a few more issues; if these are relevant, I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have MacPorts. Perhaps you can use MacPorts to install the Python of your choice, and then use the corresponding `pip` (probably `/opt/local/bin/pip` to install the necessary Python packages.

If MacPorts is something you're not using anymore, I suggest to use homebrew instead: http://mxcl.github.io/homebrew/ . Pay attention to the message you get after installing Python: it tells you that some Python scripts will be installed in `/usr/local/share/python`. In your case, this may not be an issue (the packages you listed don't install Python scripts afaik).

Keep in mind that using homebrew and MacPorts together may still mess with Python and its packages.

Finally, you need to make sure you don't keep on using the other python executable. Therefore, in your `.profile`, comment out the last two lines like this:

```
#PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
#export PATH
```

**Update**
Then, to get rid of the MacPorts reference and ensure your PATH picks up `/usr/local/bin`, change your `.profile` further to

```
# MacPorts Installer addition on 2012-03-07_at_18:55:26: adding an appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts.
#export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH    # <- comment out
# Set /usr/local/bin explicitly for Homebrew
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Start in a new Terminal (or tab) to have your settings updated.

Comment: it was tricky with my all messed up mac. But Yeah! no error messages after import pylab! Thank you!